# Passing WooCommerce Billing Address and Shipping address to Paypal

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I am passing below fields populated from checkout page to PayPal.

```
'SHIPTOSTREET'     
'SHIPTOSTREET2'    
'SHIPTOCITY'       
'SHIPTOSTATE'      
'SHIPTOZIP'        
'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE'
```

Is there any option to pass both the Shipping address and Billing address to PayPal at the same time.
?

```
'SHIPTOSTREET' => WC()->customer->get_billing_address(),
'SHIPTOSTREET2' => WC()->customer->get_billing_address_2(),
'SHIPTOCITY' => WC()->customer->get_billing_city(),
'SHIPTOSTATE' => WC()->customer->get_billing_state(),
'SHIPTOZIP' => WC()->customer->get_billing_postcode(),
'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => WC()->customer->get_billing_country(),
```

Answer (score 1):

With Express Checkout, PayPal only works with a single address.  This is one of the benefits of PayPal Checkout for buyers...they don't have to share any actual billing info with all the different sellers they buy from.

If you're working with PayPal Pro or Braintree (direct CC processing) then you would be able to send both billing and shipping to PayPal.  The billing would be used for address verification purposes, and the shipping would be used for shipping, obviously.  Of course, it's typically recommended that you only ship to addresses where AVS is a match anyway, so both would be the same.

So the short answer is no, you cannot pass a billing address in Express Checkout, but it's not needed.

Comment: Do you have any reference link from PayPal?

Comment: Not specifically, but I am the owner of [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://www.angelleye.com/product/woocommerce-paypal-plugin/) and we deal with this often.

Comment: Well, I guess you could check the [API reference for SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout-API-Operation-NVP/), and you'll see that it simply does not provide any parameters for a billing address.  It only has SHIPTONAME, SHIPTOSTREET, etc.